# R/sqldf/mclapply, How can I use sqldf and mclapply together?

Tags: r, sqldf, mclapply

Hi I am trying to use sqldf to fetch data from my database. Since sqldf will always load tcltk, I can not use mclapply function. How can I do with that?
Thanks.

Here is an example.

```
options(gsubfn.engine = "R")
require("sqldf")
require("parallel")
sqldf("select * from iris limit 5")

for ( i in 1:3) {
  mclapply(1:30, rnorm)
}
```

Comment: I have put options(gsubfn.engine = "R") in my file. I find sqldf still loads tcltk.

Comment: Yes I have read it. I can not figure out how to run mclapply after sqldf.

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
sqldf_0.4-6.4 gsubfn_0.6-3

Comment: I have verified that this is a bug in the gsubfn package.  It was fixed some time ago in the development version of gsubfn available from the gsubfn home page but I have now put it on CRAN too as gsubfn 0.6-4 .